# Divide one-to-two x-y data into top and bottom sets

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, cluster-analysis, computational-geometry

I have a data set with two y values associated with each x value. How can I divide the data into "upper" and "lower" values?

Below, I show an example with such a data set. I show an image of the desired "top" and "bottom" groupings (the red is the top and the purple is the bottom). My best idea so far is to find a line dividing the top and bottom data using an iterative approach.This solution is complicated and does not work very well, so I did not include it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# construct data using piecewise functions
x1 = np.linspace(0, 0.7, 70)
x2 = np.linspace(0.7, 1, 30)
x3 = np.linspace(0.01, 0.999, 100)
y1 = 4.164 * x1 ** 3
y2 = 1 / x2
y3 = x3 ** 4 - 0.1

# concatenate data
x = np.concatenate([x1, x2, x3])
y = np.concatenate([y1, y2, y3])

# I want to be able divide the data by top and bottom,
#  like shown in the chart. The black is the unlabeled data
#  and the red and purple show the top and bottom
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='^', s=10, c='k')
plt.scatter(x1, y1, marker='x', s=0.8, c='r')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, marker='x', s=0.8, c='r')
plt.scatter(x3, y3, marker='x', s=0.8, c='purple')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you try to find the upper and lower groups by how close the points are to each other? Eg you could put a small square around each point, then take a square and any square that intersects it are part of the same group, then continue to include other points whose square intersect with the group. Will only work if there are distinct non overlapping lines.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the moving average of the values? You can play around with the interval size, but i guess it should be relatively small.

Comment: In your specific example, the purple triangles are easily found as the lower hull of the set. Use the Graham scan algorithm (Andrew's monotone chain version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dividing line by re-ordering your data. Sort everything by x then apply a Gaussian filter. The two data sets are strictly above or below the results of the Gaussian filter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d
import numpy as np

# construct data using piecewise functions
x1 = np.linspace(0, 0.7, 70)
x2 = np.linspace(0.7, 1, 30)
x3 = np.linspace(0.01, 0.999, 100)
y1 = 4.164 * x1 ** 3
y2 = 1 / x2
y3 = x3 ** 4 - 0.1

# concatenate data
x = np.concatenate([x1, x2, x3])
y = np.concatenate([y1, y2, y3])

# I want to be able divide the data by top and bottom,
#  like shown in the chart. The black is the unlabeled data
#  and the red and purple show the top and bottom


idx = np.argsort(x)
newy = y[idx]
newx = x[idx]
gf = gaussian_filter1d(newy, 5)
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='^', s=10, c='k')
plt.scatter(x1, y1, marker='x', s=0.8, c='r')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, marker='x', s=0.8, c='r')
plt.scatter(x3, y3, marker='x', s=0.8, c='purple')
plt.scatter(newx, gf, c='orange')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would try as follows:

- sort the points by increasing X if necessary;
- maintain two indexes to the upper and lower subsets;
- moving from left to right, for every new point assign it to the closest subset and update the corresponding index.

Initialization of the process seems a little tricky. Start with the first two points (they have high chance of belonging to the same subset). Progress until the two points have a significant separation so that you are sure they belong to different subsets. Then backtrack to the left.